# Fontawesome with Bootstrap 4 implement button with an icon?

Tags: bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I'm trying to implement fornawesome in bootstrap 4. So far I was able to get all the files, but icon is not showing on the screen. Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/fontawesome.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
      <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="#" title="Help Documentation">
        <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
      </a>
      <button type="button" name="btn-help" class="btn btn-link" title="Help Documentation">
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
   </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are using fontawesome v5.9 . But you are using `<i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>` which is in `v4.7`. There are two ways to fix this. You can add `v4.7` cdn or just use fontawesomw `v5.7` icons like `<i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>` . you are missing `s` in `fa`.

use

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8b41a163ea.js"></script>
```

or

```
<i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
```

**Updated**

I also tried with with `<i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>` rather than using solid icons and changed the `CDN` which found through [all fontawesome cdn links](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome) and its working perfectly. No need to change fontawesome icons by adding **s** you can replace your `CDN` like below and its woking in chrome and firefox

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css">
```

Comment: Can you explain please? Do I need js file for font awesome. I downloaded free-5.9.0-web version and I use files from the local server.

Comment: @espresso_coffee give me couple of minutes ill post something explainable

Comment: @espresso_coffee sorry it should be `fas fa` not `fa fas`

Comment: „fas” stands for “font awesome - solid”. There are multiple flavors now: solid (fas), regular (far) and light (fal) - https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace the class `fa` for `fas` and change the link to the Font Awesome stylesheet as follows:

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css">
```

See your snippet working after those 2 changes:

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
      <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="#" title="Help Documentation">
        <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
      </a>
      <button type="button" name="btn-help" class="btn btn-link" title="Help Documentation">
    <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
   </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @NipunTharuksha: Thanks!